"load of something" vs "loads of something" -? Difference
A comic strip illustrating everyday tasks of 'The Durrell family' on the island of Corfu contains the following dialogue :

Gerald : Everyone loves swimming but I think it's boring! I prefer exploring the island! There's loads of wildlife here.

Ref. Cambridge dictionary
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/loads-of

loads of something
idiom (also a load of something)
much or many:
There were loads of people standing around a TV set in the store.
Ellie's a good student, and she has a load of friends.

Wildlife is a collective noun..
Can we use "load of wildlife" instead of "loads of wildlife" without changing the meaning?
Edit 1
Ref. Oxford Advanced Learner's dictionary says load of something can be used for unpleasant or undesirable things..
loads [pl] ~s (of sth) (infml) plenty (of sth): loads of friends/ money/time 'Do you have any change?' 'Loads!'
load of sth [sing] a lot of sth, esp sth unpleasant or undesirable: a load of rubbish! He brought round a load of old junk.
IDM get a load of sb/sth (infml esp US) to look at sb/sth: Get a load of that guy with the funny hat!

This question is similar to: "A lot of" or "lots of". If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. I agree with the answer there that lots of is more informal than a lot of, and you should be aware that metaphoric loads is far more informal than lots.

I thought a question about this quote was asked earlier, but I don't see it. Was it deleted?

@AndyBonner Phrases like loads of, wildlife is a collective noun  are not understood by non-native English learners. It is an edited version as suggested by the community.

@FumbleFingers In one of the reputed dictionaries, I found there is some difference how loads of and load of is used. It may not be same with 'lots of' and 'lot of'.

Maybe I didn't make it clear in my first comment. In almost all contexts, a load of, loads of, a lot of lots of are synonymous but load is more informal than lot, and plural is more informal than singular.

What you might have found in a dictionary is that singular a load of xxx is often a literal usage. Long ago, a load of hay, a load of firewood were specific amounts (maybe as much as a horse or mule could carry, I dunno). But loads of hay / firewood / coal wouldn't usually be used like that, and lots / a lot of... have never identified any particular amount.

For use in this sense, infml much or many as defined in Cambridge Dictionary, the OP’s quoted examples work too with their respective alternative phrases:

There's [a load of] wildlife here.


There [was a load of] people standing around a TV set in the store.


Ellie's a good student, and she has [loads of] friends.

Edit
Lots of is more informal than a lot of as explained in the comments; loads of and a load of are further down in the formality scale.
Edit 2
Loads is predominantly BrE compared to AmE in both the 2012 and 2019 corpora especially the latter.  Like lots of BrE informal terms, it carries relatively strong social status overtones.   Please see examples and more explanations in @FumbleFingers' comments.

I'm not sure that "loads of" should be any more informal than "a load of," just that they're both a touch more informal than constructions using "lots."

In very casual contexts, loads can function as an adverb meaning very much: It would help loads if you could send some money. I wouldn't say a lot is necessarily particularly informal in contexts like A lot of people need [whatever they need], but to my ear lots of people leans towards "casual". But loads is inherently so much more casual that it may be meaningless to differentiate levels of informality between singular and plural.

Thanks, @FumbleFingers and Andy Bonner.   I've edited my last paragraph.

Loads is definitely British, unlike lots, which is universal. And like lots of BrE "informal" terms, it carries relatively strong social status overtones. Some learners might wish to know that He's got loads of money is very low down the social hierarchy. A better class of people say He's got oodles / heaps / pots of money.

Thanks, @@FumbleFingers.   I have edited my answer.

'Wildlife' is a collective noun.
Collective nouns are used to refer to a group of people, animals, or things, either *as a single entity or as individuals within the group.
Collective nouns refer to a group as a whole, so they cannot be categorized as countable or uncountable. However, they can be used with both singular and plural meanings. Sometimes, collective nouns may take the plural form with 's' or 'es', but this typically refers to different groups of the same noun or is used in a general sense.
Collective nouns refer to a group as a whole, so they cannot be categorized as countable or uncountable. However, they can be used with both singular and plural meanings..
I found an answer to my question on another site.
<https://forum.thefreedictionary.com/postst8329_plural-and-singular-.aspx

Well, actually this is a little more complicated than it first seems, because "wildlife" is different from "life.".
"Wildlife" is what is known as a collective noun, meaning there is more than one member. "Family" is a similar, collective noun.
Most of the time, collective nouns are treated as singular:.
"The family is eating dinner.".
Most of the time, a family is considered a unit, with much more in common than otherwise, and thus treated as a unitary noun.
Sometimes, collective nouns are treated as plurals:.
"The family are fighting over Uncle John's will.".
In this case, the predominant consideration is for the members as individuals and what they are doing as individuals.
"The crew is bringing the ship into port.".
"The crew are bringing the ship into port.".
This is a trickier case, and neither use (plural v. singular) is incorrect.
If one is considering the crew as a team and the team actions to be coordinated, and if that is what one focuses on, then "is" would be correct.
If, on the other hand, one focuses on the individual tasks of the crew members and consider that some are concerned with the ship itself, some with passengers and baggage, and conceivably some with freight, then "are" would be correct.
"Wildlife," itself, may be used either way:.
Wildlife is in danger from climate change. (Thinking of the whole, experiencing the same threat.).
The wildlife of the area are beautiful. (Thinking of each specie as its own object of beauty.).
Or even:
As the climate of the area changes, the wildlife are adjusting, and some species may go extinct, while others increase.

